# Clear All Fields on MVC4 Razor View on both: Loading and after Back to Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, field

What is the most effective method in order to make all the fields on an MVC4 Razor empty when loading it (for example first loading or after backing to the page again)? If it is possible could you please suggest me a way with the help of Razor properties instead of using Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Please re-read your question and attempt to make it clearer.

Comment: Ok, I simplified it. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 13):

It's a little difficult to make out what you're trying to do, but let's see if I can help.

Firstly, if you simply wanted to clear out a form's values after it's been posted, you can do that like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    model = new ViewModel();

    return View(model);
}
```

Simply creating a new `ViewModel` isn't enough, as the `ModelState` dictionary will try to repopulate the form with the old values.  This does what you want, but isn't really leveraging MVC to do what you want.

The better way to do it would be to redirect back to the action you use to display your form.  Something like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new ViewModel();

    return View(model);
}
```

This is simply passing in an empty model to your form.  Once the user fills out the form, and it's posted back to the server, you can handle it like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Form data is valid so redirect back to display the form again
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }

    // If we get here, redisplay the form with the fields filled in
    // and errors shown
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I meant that if there is validation error the form will be submitted and I show another view saying Thanks. But at this stage, after pressing "Back" button on the browser, all the fields on the registration form are still on the form. Can this method let me the approach I want?

Comment: @H.Johnson This method won't prevent that.  You should read the answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189030/how-to-prevent-re-submit-of-form-when-getting-back-to-it) question.  In particular, Jodes makes a very important point: `The problem is if you want to allow the user to press back and re-submit to create a second entry, there is no way to tell if the user intended to make a second copy or not.`

Comment: @H.Johnson I should be a little more clear.  The technique I'm using above is an example of the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.  It can be used to prevent a user from receiving a popup asking them to resubmit a form, if they happened to refresh the page.  In that sense, it can reduce duplicates but, from my understanding at least, it cannot eliminate them entirely.

Comment: Actually in my project I controlled the identity number and if the same person try to make registration I warn her/him. But, I think that there must be a way when I do not have any parameter to check duplicate record and I do not use Captcha control. What would you use in order to revent the user submit the same form data by using the back button of the browser?

Comment: @H.Johnson If a user clicks back and then resubmits the form, you'd already have their registration data stored in the database.  You can then determine if the account already exists in the database. So whatever field(s) you use to determine the uniqueness of an account (e.g. a unique username or a unique email address), you'd simply check your database to see if that information already exists.  If it does, prevent the registration.  If you're worried about a user deliberately creating duplicate accounts to gain some kind of advantage on your site, that's a different thing altogether.

Comment: Of course in most cases the form behave like that, but some cases act as I wanted and I think that is the more suitable way in order to prevent from extra records.

Answer (score 5):

Simply calling a `ModelState.Clear()` will do the trick.  You shouldn't have to instantiate the view model again.

Comment: It did not work although I have used on different view call (get & post).

Answer (score 0):

A view displays (or collect) information about a Model.

So, if you pass an Empty model (that is: properties in null or blank or default values) it will "clear all fields".

All you have to do is invoking again the Action that displays the view, now passing an empty model.

**EDIT:** 
You can do it in javascript, but then you have to duplicate and maintain the logic of what are default values.

Comment: What about an example pls with using Razor or .Net properties instead of Javascript?